# Ajax not working codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this javascript

```
$('a[name=deleteButton]').on('click', function () {
    arr=[];
    var arr = $("input[name='post[]']:checked").map(function() { 
            return this.value; 
          }).get();
          var content = $(this).parents('tr').find('.key').html();
    $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {arr:arr},
   url: "../deleteRowUsingApiKey",
   success: function(results){
     alert(data);
   }
});
});
```

and in php

this is the codeigniter controller where I wanted to post the value

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
class DeleteRowUsingApiKey extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        // $this->load->model('deleteapi');
        // $this->deleteapi->deleteCheckout('CHECKvaPrfuRYzJa0MOUT');
        // echo "hi";
             echo $encrypted_data = $this->input->post('arr');

    }
}
```

The ajax is located inthe view and the php is in the controller folder,the codeigniter is installed in a folder app.Im not able to echo back the value in javascript,please help

Comment: alert(data); change data to results

Comment: also change 
echo $encrypted_data = $this->input->post('arr'); To 
echo $this->input->post('arr');

Answer (score 0):

The `URL` might be the problem.

You need to give the `absolute URL` in the `JS` function:

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/deleteRowUsingApiKey",
```

If your `ajax function` is in a `JS` file, you need to define the `base_url` before including the `JS`, for e.g:

```
<script>var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';</script>
<script src="path/to/the/ajax.js">
```

Now, you can access the `base_url` in the `ajax.js`, e.g:

```
url: base_url+"/deleteRowUsingApiKey",
```

Hope it helps.